# What does the prefit parameter in sklearn's SelectFromModel do?

Tags: feature-selection, scikit-learn

I'd like to use sklearn's [SelectFromModel](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html) to do feature selection. However, I'm not quite sure I understand the difference between `prefit=True` and `prefit=False`. According to the documentation:

```
Whether a prefit model is expected to be passed into the constructor directly or not. 
If True, transform must be called directly and SelectFromModel cannot be used with cross_val_score, GridSearchCV and similar utilities that clone the estimator. 
Otherwise train the model using fit and then transform to do feature selection.
```

I don't really understand what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prefit` parameter of `SelectFromModel` indicates if the provided estimator has already been fit to data. If the parameter is set to `True`, the `transform()` method can be called directly to transform the data according to the most important features:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression


X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, n_samples=100, n_features=5)

log_reg = LogisticRegression()
log_reg.fit(X, y)

selector = SelectFromModel(estimator=log_reg, prefit=True)

X_selected = selector.transform(X)
```

Alternatively, one can also choose to pass an estimator that has not been fitted to any data yet. In this case, `SelectFromModel` needs to first complete this step as well:

```py
X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, n_samples=100, n_features=5)

selector = SelectFromModel(estimator=LogisticRegression)

X_selected = selector.fit_transform(X)
```

The reason behind such a design is to make `SelectFromModel` compatible for use in data transformation pipelines, e.g. in cross-validation or grid search for hyperparameter tuning. Since in such pipelines a different subset of data points may be passed to the estimator in each iteration, it needs to be re-fit to each subset. This is also the reason why a `SelectFromModel` object with `prefit=True` cannot be used with e.g. `cross_val_score` or `GridSearchCV`.

Contrariwise, if `SelectFromModel` is not used in such pipelines and a fitted model is already available, setting `prefit=True` avoids re-fitting the estimator unnecessarily and saves computational resources.